# What's the (monoidal) image of a monoidal functor?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, functoriality

For an ordinary functor $F\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ of categories, there is a construction $\operatorname{im} F$, the *image* of $F$, which is again a category, and $F$ factors through that image.

Is there anything vaguely like the image of a strong monoidal functor, which should be monoidal again?

What certainly doesn't work straightforwardly is just taking the image of the underlying functor and somehow putting a monoidal structure on it. Given $X, Y\colon \mathcal{C}$, how would you define $FX \otimes FY$? If you take the tensor product in $\mathcal{D}$, the result might not be in the image of $F$, but neither can you define it to be $F(X \otimes Y)$, since $F$ might no be injective on objects (so you can't find out a unique object to start with, and there is no canonical way to choose).

I'm utterly surprised I've never encountered such a construction. The only thing I've come across is for the case of fusion categories. There, the full subcategory spanned by summands of objects in the image of $F$ can be defined.

The only thing I can come up with for plain monoidal categories is the category spanned by the image of the underlying functor and all isomorphic objects. But this doesn't have good properties if I want to extend structures on $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. For example, if I have a braiding $c_{X,Y}\colon X \otimes Y \to Y \otimes X$ on $\mathcal{C}$, I can transport it onto objects of the form $FX$, but not onto all objects isomorphic to an $FX$, since I don't know which isomorphism to transport it along.

Comment: Reading [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ternary+factorization+system) and [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff%2C+structure%2C+property) has me convinced that the right way to think of the image is "having the objects of $\mathcal C$ and morphisms of $\mathcal D$. I think the following definition works:

Comment: The monoidal category $\mathrm{1im}\;F$ has the same objects as $\mathcal C$ and its morphisms $A\rightarrow B$ are $\mathcal D(FA,FB)$. Composition is as defined in $\mathcal D$. Define $\otimes$ as in $\mathcal C$ for objects. On morphisms, use the $\otimes$ in $\mathcal D$ to get something in $\mathcal D(FA\otimes FC,FB\otimes FD)$ and then use the coherence maps of $F$ to translate this into $\mathcal D(F(A\otimes C),F(B\otimes D))$. Then the canonical functors $\mathcal C\rightarrow \mathrm{1im}\;F\rightarrow\mathcal D$ are eso and full-and-faithfull respectively, which is what we want.

Comment: In higher category theory there are different notions of image living at different categorical levels (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-image). Functors between categories have 2 notions of image, neither of which is the one you've given (which I believe fails to be invariant under equivalences). Monoidal functors should have 3 because monoidal categories live in a 3-category.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Surely two of those three images must be the same. After all monoid homomorphisms don't have two notions of image (or do they?).

Comment: Or, for that matter, ordinary functors have only one sensible notion of image I'm aware of.

Comment: @OscarCunningham, your construction is essentially the full subcategory spanned by the objects of the form $FX$. But this is very different from the mere (nonmonoidal) image of $F$ when $F$ is not full.

Comment: @Turion As Qiaochu says, there are definitely two notions of image of a functor $F:\mathcal C\rightarrow D$. The "$2$-image" is defined to be the category $\mathcal C$ with two morphisms quotiented together if they have the same image under $F$. The "$1$-image" is defined to be the full subcategory of $\mathcal D$ spanned by the objects of the form $FX$. I gave what I thought was the generalisation of the $1$-image (though Qiaochu disagrees). By "image" do you instead mean the $2$-image or something else?

Comment: @OscarCunningham, I meant the image of the underlying function on objects, as new object set and the images of the underlying functions on homsets as new homsets. So I guess, yes, that's the 2-image. And I see that the 1-image is a sensible construction that gives a factorisation for functors. Also by lowering the $n$ in $n$-image from 2 to 1 you removed the evilness that prevented me from transporting additional structure. It seems to make sense.

Comment: @Turion The description you gave doesn't define a category! If $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$, and we happen to have $FB=FC$ then $Ff$ and $Fg$ would be composable in the image, but we can't define $Fg\circ Ff$ because we want it to be $F(f\circ g)$ but $f\circ g$ isn't defined. I found this very unexpected when I learnt it, categories should have sensible images just like groups or topological spaces or anything else! But when you get used to them the $1$- and $2$-images are very friendly.

Comment: @Oscar: monoid homomorphisms have two notions of image because monoids live in a 2-category (thinking of them as one-object categories); just take your definitions for a functor and specialize them to one-object categories.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Then the $1$-image is just the codomain monoid. So I was wrong above, it's not that two of the three images of a monoidal functor coalesce, it's that one of them is just equal to the codomain. Either way, only two are non-trivial.

Comment: @OscarCunningham, why would that be a problem at all? It often happen that $Fg \circ Ff$ can be defined and $f \circ g$ is not defined. Take the discrete category on 2 objects and map it on the terminal category.

Comment: @OscarCunningham, I see, the problem is that $Fg \circ Ff$ is not in the image I defined. Then yet another definition of image would be completing my image under $- \circ -$. I wonder whether this is the same as the 2-image.

Answer (score 4):

Let $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a strong monoidal functor. Since monoidal categories are non-strict structures in the sense that e.g. associativity of $\otimes$ only holds up to isomorphism, it makes sense to look at those objects of $\mathcal{D}$ which are isomorphic to objects of the form $F(X)$, where $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$. These constitute a full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$, which contains the unit object and is closed under tensor products, hence inherits a monoidal structure.

If (only) $\mathcal{C}$ has a braiding, there is no reason to expect that it induces a braiding on the image, since this image depends on $F$. For this, we should require that $\mathcal{D}$ is also braided and that $F$ is a braided monoidal functor. It follows that the image, as defined above, carries a braiding induced by $\mathcal{D}$, and that $F$ factors as a braided monoidal functor into it.