# Is the essential image of a monoidal functor a monoidal category?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the awnsers to this question

[What's the (monoidal) image of a monoidal functor?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249197/whats-the-monoidal-image-of-a-monoidal-functor)

it is argued that the full image of a monoidal functor can be viewed as its "monoidal image".

The **essential image** of a functor is defined in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+image.

**My question** is now whether or not there is a canonical monoidal structure on the essential image.

Comment: I assume that that by "monoidal functor" you mean "strong monoidal functor" $F: C \to D$, as in the question you link to. HeinrichD's answer over there actually discusses the essential image of $F$: the full subcategory of $D$ spanned by the objects _isomorphic_ to those of the form $Fc$, and explains that this inherits a canonical monoidal structure from $D$. Does that answer your question?